# Convert OGRE::Image to cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, ogre

I am new to [OGRE library](http://www.ogre3d.org/). I have a human model in OGRE, I get the projection of the model in 'orginalImage' variable. I would like to perform some image processing using openCV. So I am trying to achieve OGRE::Image to cv::Mat conversion.

```
Ogre::Image orginalImage = get2dProjection();

//This is an attempt to convert the image
cv::Mat destinationImage(orginalImage.getHeight(), orginalImage.getWidth(), CV_8UC3, orginalImage.getData());

imwrite("out.png", destinationImage);
```

I get following error:

```
realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f9e2ca13840 ***
```

On the similar note, I tried following as my second attempt

```
cv::Mat cvtImgOGRE2MAT(Ogre::Image imgIn) {
    //Result image intialisation:
    int imgHeight = imgIn.getHeight();
    int imgWidth  = imgIn.getWidth();
    cv::Mat imgOut(imgHeight, imgWidth, CV_32FC1);

    Ogre::ColourValue color;
    float gray;
    cout << "Converting " << endl; 
    for(int r = 0; r < imgHeight; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < imgWidth; c++){
            color = imgIn.getColourAt(r,c,0);
            gray = 0.2126 * color.r + 0.7152 * color.g + 0.0722 * color.b;
            imgOut.at<float>(r,c) = gray;
        }
    } 
    return imgOut;
```

}

I get same error when I do one of the following:

```
imshow("asdfasd", imgOut); 
imwrite("asdfasd.png", imgOut);
```

Comment: `imwrite("out.png", cvImage);` Is that a typo? Should be `destinationImage`

Comment: Is this the exact way the code is in your application?

Comment: Basically I have:
Ogre::TexturePtr  rtt_texture;
Ogre::RenderTexture *renderTexture; there is some operation in between and then renderTexture->update(); rtt_texture->convertToImage(originalImage);

Comment: Have you tested if `originalImage` is actually a valid `Ogre::Image`? Does it contain valid pixel data?

Comment: Yes, it is valid because originalImage.save("test.png"); saves an image file to the disk.

Comment: what's your Ogre::PixelComponentType and Ogre::PixelFormat?? does your ogre image go out of scope or is released during cv::Mat existance?

Comment: @Micka PixelFormat is PF_BYTE_RGBA.

Comment: please try cv::Mat destinationImage(orginalImage.getHeight(), orginalImage.getWidth(), CV_8UC4, orginalImage.getData());

Comment: @Micka Thanks, This approach copies the values correctly to cv::Mat. I then split channels and then merge to form a BGR image in opencv. But when I used imwrite or imshow, I still get the realloc error.

Comment: @Micka Would you like to post your answer so that I can close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately I have no experience with OGRE, so I can just talk about OpenCV and what I've seen in Ogre documentation and poster's comments.

The first thing to mention is that the Ogre image' `PixelFormat is PF_BYTE_RGBA` (from comments) which is (according to OGRE documentation) a 4 byte pixel format, so the cv::Mat type should be `CV_8UC4` if image data should be given by pointer. In addition, openCV best supports BGR images, so a color conversion might be best to save/display.

please try:

```
Ogre::Image orginalImage = get2dProjection();

//This is an attempt to convert the image
cv::Mat destinationImage(orginalImage.getHeight(), orginalImage.getWidth(), CV_8UC4, orginalImage.getData());

cv::Mat resultBGR;
cv::cvtColor(destinationImage, resultBGR, CV_RGBA2BGR);

imwrite("out.png", resultBGR);
```

in your second example I wondered what is wrong there, until I saw `color = imgIn.getColourAt(r,c,0);` which might be wrong since most image APIs use `.getPixel(x,y)` so I confirmed that this is the same for OGRE. Please try this:

```
cv::Mat cvtImgOGRE2MAT(Ogre::Image imgIn) 
{
    //Result image intialisation:
    int imgHeight = imgIn.getHeight();
    int imgWidth  = imgIn.getWidth();
    cv::Mat imgOut(imgHeight, imgWidth, CV_32FC1);

    Ogre::ColourValue color;
    float gray;
    cout << "Converting " << endl; 
    for(int r = 0; r < imgHeight; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < imgWidth; c++)
        {
            // next line was changed
            color = imgIn.getColourAt(c,r,0);
            gray = 0.2126 * color.r + 0.7152 * color.g + 0.0722 * color.b;
            // this access is right
            imgOut.at<float>(r,c) = gray;
        }
    } 
    return imgOut;  

    // depending of what you want to do with the image, "float" Mat type assumes what image intensity values are within 0..1 (displaying) or 0..255 (imwrite)

}
```

if you still get realloc errors, can you please try to find the exact line of code where it happens?

One thing I didnt consider yet is the real memory layout of OGRE images. It might be possible that they use some kind of aligned memory, where each pixel-row is aligned to have a memory size as a multiple of 4 or 16 or sth. (which might be more efficient, e.g. to use SSE instructions or sth.) If that is the case, you can't use the first method but you would have to change it to `cv::Mat destinationImage(orginalImage.getHeight(), orginalImage.getWidth(), CV_8UC4, orginalImage.getData(), STEPSIZE);` where `STEPSIZE` is the number of BYTES for each pixel ROW! But the second version should work then!